# Infinite scroll in viewpager2 and tablayoutmediator

Tags: android, kotlin, slide, android-viewpager2

I'm trying to get bidirectional infinite scroll in my viewpager 2, but I can't seem to see how to reach the solution, so any help will be appreciated.

Adapter:

```
class LandingViewPagerAdapter(fa: FragmentActivity, val slides: List<DtoSlide>) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fa) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return slides.size
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return LandingSlideFragment().newInstance(slides[position])
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
private fun setupViewPager(slides: List<data.network.entities.DtoSlide>) {
        pagerAdapter = LandingViewPagerAdapter(this, slides)
        viewpager_landing.adapter = pagerAdapter
        TabLayoutMediator(viewpager_dots, viewpager_landing) { tab, position -> }.attach()
    }
```